# Packages Upgrade Manager doesn't work in Ubuntu Studio 19.10

Tags: package-management, upgrade

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10, upgraded from 19.04, upgraded from 18.04.3.

Even the fact that the system is working so fine with Audio, Midi, Video and Images... The standard Menu app "Packages Upgrade Manager" doesn't work!

It seems to be working on... something (HHD red light is on), but... I have been waiting for more than one hour and... Nothing!

I have to perform a manual upgrade process, with the Terminal session line commands (apt dist-upgrade, apt update, apt upgrade) to get the normal upgrades.

When I use the line command pkcon refresh force, it seems to do something... Forever!

[image]

Is it a known bug? Is it something wrong in my system, only?

How can I work around it?

Comment: `pkcon refresh force` please and `pkcon get-updates` please.

Comment: it would be nice to show the output please edit your question for that